# Linux base device not getting shutdown

Tags: linux, init, shutdown, reboot, runlevel

I try to shutdown my embedded system running with Linux environment using `shutdown -h now`. But it is rebooting my system again. So can anyone give me suggestion how to shutdown my system or resolve this issue.

Or any possible reason of this issue?

Linux version is 2.37

Comment: Try `shutdown -p now`

Comment: Also, do you know if this is really a sysvinit Linux system or is shutdown passed to systemd `systemctl`?

Comment: @jaybee : I also tried it, It is not working.

Comment: @David C. Rankin : I don't have that much of knowledge about it, So please can you direct me how to debug this issue.

Comment: type ``shutdown --help`` and find out yourself :)

Comment: @ jan groth: I already try all option coming with shutdown and poweroff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question is

```
shutdown -P now
```

Jaybee is near correct, where p should be upper case.

Comment: It is not working, I try to use each and every option coming with poweroff and shutdown but system is always rebooting.

Comment: Then this most probably seems like bios issue of the embedded system you use. One such issue in Intel is reported here
https://communities.intel.com/thread/47751?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: Also notice -P option with shutdown is usable when option -h is there otherwise it is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using
`poweroff` command.
When posting a question please mention the Linux kernel version being used.

Comment: Sorry my kernel version is 2.37, And also using poweroff system is not getting powered off, it is rebooting.

Comment: Try `halt -p` or `halt -f`. `-f` is the force option. It is supposed to shutdown the system instantly. But its behaviour may not be consistent. Desktops might hang on running this command.